# PHP SQL Query to Select Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am trying to make a `select` have some pre-loaded `options`.

I have a php script that queries for these options, and I want to load them into the `select` on an html page.

My attempt right now..

HTML

```
<html>
<head>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usersList").click(function()
  {    
     $.getJSON('states.php', function(data) {   
        $("#usersList").html(data.value);
     });   
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Find Users in: <select id="usersList" name="usersList">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost","helloja2_Austin","mysql"); 
 mysql_select_db("helloja2_Friends") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT State FROM Clients ORDER BY State ASC") 
 or die(mysql_error());

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 $ary[] =$info['State'];
 } 
 mysql_close();
 ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP works fine, but I am not sure how to get that information into my `select`.

All help appreciated!

Comment: is your jquery working?

Comment: You're not even adding jQuery to your page as far as I can see.

Comment: Thus why I am asking for help...I am not sure where to pull/put this stuff at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

The html select-tag needs to get closed like this:

```
<select></select>
```

Next:

Your `$ary` isnt defined anywhere and it isnt returned anywhere
Use `json_decode();` to return json
(and dont use any html head/body in your php file which outputs json)

Your json.php:

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost","helloja2_Austin","mysql"); 
 mysql_select_db("helloja2_Friends") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT State FROM Clients ORDER BY State ASC") 
 or die(mysql_error());

 $ary = Array();

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
      array_push($ary,$info["state"]);
 } 
 mysql_close();
 echo json_encode($ary);
 ?>
```

Next:

You need to append option tags to your select with jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usersList").click(function()
  {    
     $.getJSON('states.php', function(data) {   
         $.each(data,function(key,indata){

             $("#usersList").append($("<option>",{
                   html : indata
             }));

      })});   
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! couple of questions though if you don't mind (I want to learn all of this). 1. At the end of my PHP I used `print json_encode($ary);` as posted by fortune and that worked fine, but swapping it with `json_decode();` did not work, why is that? 2. Could you attempt to briefly explain the `$.each` condition?

Comment: $.each() is jquerys short function for for() or foreach() with a few benefits

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have jquery library is missing. Please add it after the `<head>` tag and try:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

In the php, after `mysql_close()`. Add

```
print json_encode($ary);
```

Comment: Added, but I am not sure where to pull/put stuff still